# Remove specific values based on the presence of one value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a roller that randomly picks from one or two lists to assemble a new vertical list. I'm trying to prevent a specific few values from appearing together in one assembled list. These values, for reference, are `W-2`, `W-1`, `W-0`, `W+1`, `W+2`, and `W+3`. There should only ever be **one** of these in a list. For an example, here's something that my roller may generate:

```
Tn  
AA  
En  
SpM  
W-1  
Sp-2  
W-2  
Co
```

The problem here is that `W-1` *and* `W-2` are on this same list. Ideally every "W" cell *except for one* would be made blank or prevented from happening to begin with. Whether the one remainder is random or the first/last one doesn't matter (if I can be specific though, the ideal would be for the highest number to be left. So between `W-1` and `W+2`, `W-1` would be removed. However I'll gladly accept the simplest route whatever it may be.)

[Here's a copy of my roller](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d-F_pWkNWPNB4M-mNdW41WTdO4GyxPe34G08hhdVpuc/edit?usp=sharing).

This is on the `Data` sheet.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a easier way to do this, but, Here's a solution:
Add a extra column after BH

BI2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(BH2:BH27,--REGEXREPLACE(BH2:BH27,"W(.*)", "$1"),0),COUNTA(BH2:BH27)-SUM(--REGEXMATCH(BH2:BH27,"^W"))+1,1))
```

We're sorting by the `W` in the descending order and constraining it to the first result only.